# Generating a dictionary of dataframes based on file names

Tags: python, pandas

The `dfs` is a dictionary of pandas dataframes for each file that ends with the specified substring. The dataframes are created using `sc.read_10x_h5` and are labelled using the substring before the first `_` of each corresponding file name.

My code returned an empty `dfs`.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import scanpy as sc

dfs = {}

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk("../single_cell_dataset/"):
     for file in files:
            if file.endswith(("_ccRCC.h5")):
                id = file.split("_")[0]
                dfs[id] = sc.read_10x_h5(file, genome="GRCh38", backup_url=None)    
                print(dfs)
```

Input:

`../single_cell_dataset/`

```
GSM4819725_SI_18854_ccRCC.h5
GSM4819726_SI_18856_ccRCC.h5
GSM4819727_SI_18855_normal.h5
GSM4819728_SI_19704_ccRCC.h5
GSM4819729_SI_19703_normal.h5
GSM4819730_SI_21255_normal.h5
GSM4819731_SI_21256_normal.h5
GSM4819732_SI_21561_chRCC.h5
GSM4819733_SI_22369_ccRCC.h5
GSM4819734_SI_22368_normal.h5
GSM4819735_SI_22605_ccRCC.h5
GSM4819736_SI_22604_normal.h5
GSM4819737_SI_23459_ccRCC.h5
GSM4819738_SI_23843_ccRCC.h5
```

Expected output:

`dfs` as a dictionary containing the dataframes named as, e.g. `GSM4819725`, `GSM4819726`

Comment: When reading the files, you should specify the (relative) path to the filenames, not just the filenames.